# How to make two block horizontal when using inline block?

Tags: html, css

```css
.roles span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <img alt="test" src="images/02_button_add.png">
  <span>AlexAlexAl exAlexAlex AlexAlexAlex </span>
</div>
```

I am using `display:inline-block;` to put `span` text next to my img.
However, the image is on the left-bottom side of my span.

How to make them horizontal?

Comment: what you need as answer ?? Can you clear bit more??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use vertical-align:top to your image.

```
.roles img
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gox5droc/

This will ensure the image will be aligned on top of the div.

Answer (score 1):

For **Vertical** Add the `width` to `image` tag.

```css
.roles span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <img alt="test" src="images/02_button_add.png" style="width:100%">
  <span>AlexAlexAl exAlexAlex AlexAlexAlex </span>
</div>
```

For **Horizontal** Add the `vertical-align` to `span` tag.

```css
.roles span {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <img alt="test" src="images/02_button_add.png">
  <span>AlexAlexAl exAlexAlex AlexAlexAlex </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `float:left`, to both `img` and `span` and add width to `img`

```css
.roles img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
  float: left;
}

.roles span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <img alt="test" src="images/02_button_add.png">
  <span>AlexAlexAl exAlexAlex AlexAlexAlex </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.roles span {
  width:80px;
display: table;
}

img {
vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><img alt="test" src="images/02_button_add.png"></div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;"><span>AlexAlexAl exAlexAlex AlexAlexAlex </span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 display :  tags in one element are not good idea, the later one will override the first one.